# Node Fibers Trouble with Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, future, node-fibers

I'm trying to write a simple authentication backend for Meteor that authenticates against an LDAP server. I need the function registered as login handler (the input to `Accounts.registerLoginHandler`) to return the `id` the of the user just logged in.

The problem I think lies in the Fiber I've created, `getUserId`, and that it's not returning `id` like I want it to. I know it has to be in a Fiber or else meteor gets angry and throws errors. Even though the log right before the `yield` shows me the `id` isn't undefined, `getUserId.run()` always returns undefined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
Accounts.registerLoginHandler(function(loginRequest) { 

    console.log("In login handler");

    return auth.authenticate(loginRequest.username, loginRequest.password, function(err, ldap_user) {

        if (err){
            // ldap authentications was failed
            console.log("Login failed");
            return undefined;
        }
        else {
            // authentication was successful
            console.log("Login success");

            // extracting team name from ldap record
            var equals = ldap_user.memberOf.indexOf("=");
            var comma = ldap_user.memberOf.indexOf(",");
            var team_name = ldap_user.memberOf.slice(equals+1,comma);

            // add user if they don't already exist

            var getUserId = Fiber( function() { // Meteor code must be ran within a fiber
                var id = null;
                var user = Meteor.users.findOne({username: loginRequest.username});
                if(!user) {

                    // insert user and kick back id
                    id = Meteor.users.insert({username: loginRequest.username,
                                              profile : {team : team_name}
                                             });
                    console.log('no user found, creating' + id);

                } else { 

                    id = user._id; 
                    console.log('user found, returning id' + id);

                }

                console.log('id: '+id);
                Fiber.yield(id);  // return id
            });

            // send logged in users if by executing the fiber
            return {id: getUserId.run()};
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to instead needing to use `Meteor.bindEnvironment` to control the scope of the (environment) variables and fibers in use.

A good three-step tutorial on the subject is found here:

1. https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/nodejs-introducing-fibers
2. https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-dynamic-scoping-with-environment-variables
3. https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-what-is-meteor-bindenvironment

My take on your code would be something like this (which in a similar problem worked for me):

```
Accounts.registerLoginHandler(function(loginRequest) { 

    console.log("In login handler");

    var boundAuthenticateFunction = Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err, ldap_user) {
        if (err){
            // ldap authentications was failed
            console.log("Login failed");
            return undefined;
        }
        else {
            // authentication was successful
            console.log("Login success");

            // extracting team name from ldap record
            var equals = ldap_user.memberOf.indexOf("=");
            var comma = ldap_user.memberOf.indexOf(",");
            var team_name = ldap_user.memberOf.slice(equals+1,comma);

            // add user if they don't already exist

            var id = null;
            var user = Meteor.users.findOne({username: loginRequest.username});
            if(!user) {

                // insert user and kick back id
                id = Meteor.users.insert({username: loginRequest.username,
                                          profile : {team : team_name}
                                         });
                console.log('no user found, creating' + id);

            } else { 

                id = user._id; 
                console.log('user found, returning id' + id);

            }

            console.log('id: '+id);

            return {id: id};
        }
    }, function(e){throw e;});

  return auth.authenticate(loginRequest.username, loginRequest.password, boundAuthenticateFunction);
});
```

Mind, the code sample above is untested...